# Изменение активного пункта меню при прокрутке страницы

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Есть страница с пятью разделами. Есть меню, по клику на пункт которого, происходит прокрутка к соответствующему разделу.

**Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке страницы колесом мыши, пункт меню изменялся в соответствии с текущим блоком?** Например как реализовано **[здесь](http://bootstrap-ru.com/scaffolding.php)**.

Вот то, что есть сейчас - http://jsfiddle.net/F2Uus/2/

При этом данный код почему-то не возвращает к блоку #home при клике на соответствующую ссылку.

Помогите осуществить данный эффект и разобраться почему страница не прокручивается к блоку #home.

Спасибо.

Comment: у меня дежавю... в том примере сделано вот так: [scrollspy](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy)

Comment: location.hash в примере вообще отсутствует

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

```js
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
  topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
  topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
  // All list items
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
  // Anchors corresponding to menu items
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  // Get container scroll position
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

  // Get id of current scroll item
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  // Get the id of the current element
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    // Set/remove active class
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 6000px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
#top-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#top-menu li {
  float: left;
}
#top-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 25px 7px 25px;
  width: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease-out;
  transition: .5s all ease-out;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#top-menu a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
#top-menu li.active a {
  border-top: 3px solid #333;
  color: #333;
}
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}
#bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px;
}
#baz {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="top-menu">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Top</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#baz">Baz</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a id="foo">Foo</a>


<a id="bar">Bar</a>


<a id="baz">Baz</a>
```

Comment: +1. Осталось только удалить изъян, который присутствует и в приведенном ТС примере: `location.hash` нужно менять и тогда, когда проскроллил до какой-то метки, а не только при клике по пункту меню.